# How can I create a radio button for each entry in a csv file on python using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm developping a tool to help me do my "chores" of calculation for a TTRPG, I need to be able to select what is the class of the character I'm creating with radio button while taking the number and name of options from a csv, so I can add, edit and delete classes without having to re-do the whole code each time.

I use classic button for now but by proceeding like this, creating a new button when creating a new race/class is really hard if not impossible and I saw something about creating radio button for each entry in a csv file but I believe this was with another language. I made some search about this to make it with tkinter but couldn't find anything. Here is my in-development code :

```
def Enemy_Race_Select(type):
    windowRace=tkinter.Tk()
    windowRace.title("FE TTRPG Tools - Enemy Stats Calculators - Race Select")
    windowRace.geometry('600x400')

    buttonBackStatsR = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = 'Go Back', command=windowRace.destroy)
    buttonBackStatsR.pack()

    labelInRace = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Choose your race")
    labelInRace.pack()

    labelHum = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Human")
    labelHum.pack()

    buttonRaceHum = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Human", command=lambda: Enemy_Class_Select(type,1))
    buttonRaceHum.pack()

    labelTag = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Tagüel")
    labelTag.pack()

    buttonRaceTag = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Tagüel")
    buttonRaceTag.pack()

    labelMan = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Manakete")
    labelMan.pack()

    buttonRaceMan = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Manakete")
    buttonRaceMan.pack()

    labelHTa = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Half-Tagüel")
    labelHTa.pack()

    buttonRaceHTa = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Half-Tagüel")
    buttonRaceHTa.pack()

    labelHMa = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Half-Manakete")
    labelHMa.pack()

    buttonRaceHMa = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Half-Manakete")
    buttonRaceHMa.pack()

    labelHTM = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Half-Tagüel-Manakete")
    labelHTM.pack()

    buttonRaceHTM = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Half-Tagüel-Manakete")
    buttonRaceHTM.pack()

    buttonCustomRace = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text="Custom class")
    buttonCustomRace.pack()

    buttonCreateRace=tkinter.Button(windowRace, text="Create a custom class", command=lambda: Race_creation())
    buttonCreateRace.pack()
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want.  Provide a few sample data in the CSV file and the expected result.

Comment: I want to have my "Race" csv with all the race stored : `Human, 15, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 <br> Tagüel, 15, 10, -10, 15, 10, 0, -10, 0, 0 <br> Manakete, 20, 10, -10, -10, -10, 10, 20, 0 <br> Half-Tagüel, 17, 15, -5, 5, 5, 0, -5, 0, 0` and I expect as result something like : RadioButton1(tagged with the first column of first entry) RadioButton2(tagged with the first column of the second entry) and so on but in my code I have a function so the user can add lines to the csv and I want that, when you add a line to the csv, a new radio button is created tagged with the first value of the entry.

Comment: Do you mean that radiobuttons with text "Human", "Tagüel", "Manakete" and "Half-Tagüel" will be created? If it is, I don't think it is difficult as you said in other comment that you know how to create radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***like this ?***

```
import csv
import tkinter as tk

# CSV data
data = [
    ["Warrior", 15, 63, 98, 74, 35, 46, 87, 25, 41, 36],
    ["Berserk", 24, 36, 51, 98, 74, 21, 34, 19, 74, 61],
    ["x", 24, 36, 51, 98, 74, 21, 34, 19, 74, 61],
    ["y", 24, 36, 51, 98, 74, 21, 34, 19, 74, 61],
    ["z", 24, 36, 51, 98, 74, 21, 34, 19, 74, 61]
]

# Create a CSV file
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerows(data)

# Create a GUI window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Radio Buttons")

# Read CSV data and create radio buttons
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    
    for row in csvreader:
        label_text = row[0]
        
        radio_button = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=label_text, value=label_text)
        radio_button.pack(anchor=tk.W)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> i didn't get it completely what you wanna do but here is example of
> radio button:

---

```
import tkinter
def Enemy_Race_Select(type):
    windowRace=tkinter.Tk()
    windowRace.title("FE TTRPG Tools - Enemy Stats Calculators - Race Select")
    windowRace.geometry('600x400')

    rb = tkinter.Radiobutton(windowRace,text='radio button',value='1',command=lambda:print('somthing'))
    rb.pack()

    buttonBackStatsR = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = 'Go Back', command=windowRace.destroy)
    buttonBackStatsR.pack()

    labelInRace = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Choose your race")
    labelInRace.pack()

    labelHum = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Human")
    labelHum.pack()

    buttonRaceHum = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Human", command=lambda: Enemy_Class_Select(type,1))
    buttonRaceHum.pack()

    labelTag = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Tagüel")
    labelTag.pack()

    buttonRaceTag = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Tagüel")
    buttonRaceTag.pack()

    labelMan = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Manakete")
    labelMan.pack()

    buttonRaceMan = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Manakete")
    buttonRaceMan.pack()

    labelHTa = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Half-Tagüel")
    labelHTa.pack()

    buttonRaceHTa = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Half-Tagüel")
    buttonRaceHTa.pack()

    labelHMa = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Half-Manakete")
    labelHMa.pack()

    buttonRaceHMa = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Half-Manakete")
    buttonRaceHMa.pack()

    labelHTM = tkinter.Label(windowRace, text = "Do a Half-Tagüel-Manakete")
    labelHTM.pack()

    buttonRaceHTM = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text = "Half-Tagüel-Manakete")
    buttonRaceHTM.pack()

    buttonCustomRace = tkinter.Button(windowRace, text="Custom class")
    buttonCustomRace.pack()

    buttonCreateRace=tkinter.Button(windowRace, text="Create a custom class", command=lambda: Race_creation())
    buttonCreateRace.pack()

    windowRace.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Enemy_Race_Select('x')
```

Comment: I know how to create radio button, what I want is to have a csv file with someting like this:
Warrior, 15, 63, 98, 74, 35, 46, 87, 25, 41, 36
Berserk, 24, 36, 51, 98, 74, 21, 34, 19, 74, 61
And have a number of radio buttons equal to the number of rows that takes the first column of each entry to labbel the radio button